# Как можно параллельно использовать WebClient.DownloadString?

Tags: c#, .net, tpl, распараллеливание

Есть коллекция ссылок и нужно скачать файлы по данным ссылкам.

Но как это правильно сделать параллельно?

Например, предварительно сконфигурированный WebClient валится с ошибкой, что не поддерживает конкуренцию.

Создавать его на каждой итерации, на мой взгляд, некорректно.

Неужели для данной задачи не подойдет TPL и нужно ручками создавать TASK'и?

Answer (score 2):

`WebClient` легковесный. Создавайте по штуке на загрузку и не парьтесь.

Расходы на создание объекта ничтожны по сравнению с расходами на коммуникацию по сети.